# Are there halal bitcoin trading sites?

Tags: halal-haram, money, internet

Any halal sites to trade in bitcoin and other Crypto Currencies?
I am now using yobit.com if it's haram please let me know, there is this site called www.gdax.com and I don't know if it's halal or haram.

Comment: It's halal while it grows, and haram when it goes down. So you need to keep buying and hodling. Disclaimer: I own bitcoins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no ruling on using bitcoin in islam.
Bitcoin is like virtual cash, so it depends on you how you use that. As long as you don't trade illegal or forbidden materials, every bitcoin trading site cosidered as a halal.
So you dont need to worry about this.

Comment: Welcome brother -zaki

Comment: Who issues a ruling? If there are 2 contradicting rulings, which will you follow?